# Screenshot is not getting displayed in TestNGResults under Jenkins

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins

I am using onTestFailure method to display error screenshot in TestNG results. I am using Jenkins to run my test but image is not getting displayed in TestNG results however it is showing it as a link and nothing is happening on clicking this scattered image link. When I copy image link using mouse and trying open it in a browser then image is getting displayed correctly which means path to image is correct.

```
public class ScreenshotListener extends  TestListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss");
        String methodName = result.getName();
        //String pathToScreen;

        if(!result.isSuccess()){
            File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)GlobalVar.wDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            try {
                String reportDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).getAbsolutePath() + "/target/surefire-reports";
                File destFile = new File((String) reportDirectory+"/failure_screenshots/"+methodName+"_"+formater.format(calendar.getTime())+".png");

                FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, destFile);
                Reporter.log("<a href='"+ destFile.getAbsolutePath() + "'> <img src='"+ destFile.getAbsolutePath() + "' height='100' width='100'/> </a><br />");
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect image link should display proper screenshot of error but it is showing blank screenshot. I have attached the screenshot of TestNGResults[image]

FURTHER INVESTIGATION RESULT:

I investigated it further and found the reason of not displaying the screenshot. Actually screenshot path is coming as **C:\SelWrokspaceLuna 18 May\RDTest\target\surefire-reports\failure_screenshots\  but jenkin workspace path is **http://localhost:8080/job/firstjob/ws/target/surefire-reports/failure_screenshots/

Can anyone suggest how to get path of Jenkin workspace in selenium script? so that i can give jenkin workspace path in my HTML. Basically how to know this path **http://localhost:8080/job/firstjob/ws** in selenium script

Comment: My initial guess is that either a) the path is wrong in Jenkins, or b)Jenkins is not saving the images that are generated

Comment: I checked both...Images are available at required location which is shown in left bottom of above screenshot attached

Comment: I investigated it further and found the reason of not displaying the screenshot.Actualy screenshot path is coming as C:\SelWrokspaceLuna 18 May\RDTest\target\surefire-reports\failure_screenshots\  but jenkin workspace path is http://localhost:8080/job/firstjob/ws/target/surefire-reports/failure_screenshots/    Can anyone suggest how to get path of Jenkin workspace in selenium script?

Comment: Did you find the solution?