# ScreenShot Not showing in testNg Report plugin

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, testng

I have an issue where the screenshots that i take dont show in the TestNg Report Plugin i am pretty sure that the probleme is the path i am giving them but i dont know what other path i can give is there a solution ?

My screenshot taking code :

```
public void ScreenShot() {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH_mm_ss");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    String destDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + "test-output/ScreenShots";
    String FileName = "SoftAssertScreenshot_" + dtf.format(now) + ".png";
    String DestFile = destDir + "/" + FileName;
    Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(1000)).takeScreenshot(driver);
    BufferedImage image = screenshot.getImage(); 
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File(DestFile));
        System.out.println("test");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Reporter.log("</br><font color='#73a9d0'>***************Screen Of the error****************</font>");
    Reporter.log("</br><img id='ErrorResult' src='" + DestFile + "' style='width:600px'/>");
}
```

What shows in testng report :
[![Image of testng result][1]][1]

Html in testng :

```
<img id="ErrorResult" src="C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\07zr-aut\Demo_Automatisation/test-output/ScreenShots/SoftAssertScreenshot_2021-11-24 08_50_12.png" style="width:600px">
```

Thanks for the help !
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zp1Y.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same code but seeing attached images.

**Code**:

```
String DestFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Data/SO.png";
Reporter.log("</br><font color='#73a9d0'>***************Screen Of the error****************</font>");
Reporter.log("</br><img id='ErrorResult' src='" + DestFile + "' style='width:600px'/>");
```

**Output**:

[image]

**HTML**:

```
<img id="ErrorResult" src="C:\Users\Nandan\EclipseWorkspace\Selenium3_SO/Data/SO.png" style="width:600px">
```

There is nothing wrong with your `Reporter.log` code. Please try the below,

- Check is the image really exists in location `C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\07zr-aut\Demo_Automatisation/test-output/ScreenShots/SoftAssertScreenshot_2021-11-24 08_50_12.png`
- Put a debug point after line `ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File(DestFile));` to confirm image is successfully written in the given location.
- `screenshot.getImage();` what is the purpose of `getImage()` method? Does it returning `RenderedImage`? If yes, where are you passing the file location? I am doing like below below and it is working. Are you following same approach?

```
String DestFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Data/"+imageName+".png";
Image image = ImageIO.read(new File(DestFile));
BufferedImage buffered = (BufferedImage) image;
ImageIO.write(buffered, "PNG", new File(DestFile));
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54190259/unable-to-view-screenshots-in-jenkins-reports) should help you. You need to find out the exact location of screenshots folder in Jenkins workspace and update `String destDir`

Comment: The same code gives me a correct page if i check it in eclipse the photo are showing and all is good getimage() as i understood groupps the multiple part of my image in one big one and the file location is sent in DestFile the probleme is that the path when taken by jenkins isnt working btw i am using jenkins localy

Comment: Have you configured TestNG report plugin in Jenkins?

Comment: i didnt configure the testng it self i configured the Batch i put in Publish TestNG Results TestNG XML report pattern "**/testng-results.xml"

Comment: Am i just stupid and that s the problem if my fil exist in /test-output/screenShots and the Testng-results exist too in test-output that s why it will never work ?

Comment: No I guess. It should not happen even if both stays under `/test-output/`

Comment: i tried it still didnt work

Comment: I found similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484416/screenshot-is-not-getting-displayed-in-testngresults-under-jenkins

Comment: Yeah i saw it too but it doesnt have a solution

Comment: This should help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54190259/unable-to-view-screenshots-in-jenkins-reports you need to find out the exact location of screenshots folder in jenkins workspace and update `String destDir `

Comment: In the question you have mentioned the screenshot location of local machine. See the location in Jenkins report and update it accordingly.

Comment: the problem with giving it the absolute path of jenkins i will have error images if i execute it from eclipse